# Sending key strokes to a window

Tags: windows-8.1, autohotkey

I want to use AutoHotkey to run a program and send some keystrokes. 
But I don't get it to work. The program pops up, and then nothing happens.

Here is what I have so far:

```
run, c:\windows\sysnative\gfxv4_0.exe
WinActivate, "Intel(R) Graphics Control Panel"
SendInput {Tab}{Tab}{Tab}{Tab}{Tab}{Tab}{Tab}{Tab}{Tab}{Enter}
```

Just for testing, I have also tried to send some keys to notepad, but that doesn't work either.  The notepad window pops up, but then nothing:

```
run notepad.exe
WinActivate "Unbenannt - Editor"
SendInput abc{Tab}{Tab}xyz
```

I have also tried `WinActivate` without parameters, but no results either. Have also tried with `Send`, `SendPlay`, `SendEvent` and `SendRaw`. No change.

System is Windows 8.1 64 Bit, latest Service Packs. 
Core i7, 8 GB, 2 screens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove the quotes
   The parameters of AHK commands are literal strings unless specified otherwise in the help for a command or you explicitly make the parameter an expression: `WinActivate, % "some string"`
2. Wait for the window to appear before activating it because launching an application takes time:
   `WinWait Intel(R) Graphics Control Panel`
3. Maybe there's ® instead of (R). Use the exact window title text from Window Spy application that comes with AutoHotkey.

Comment: Yes that did the job! - Removing the quotes and `WinWait`. **So great!** Thanks for the explanation!